# Function that splits money into notes

Tags: python

I have to write a function that takes an “amount” of money as an argument. Then to take the “amount” of money as user input and pass the value to the function parameter. After that have to implement the function and calculate how that money can be split into 500, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, and 1 taka notes.
Then print the returned value in the function call.

If the money is 1234, then the function should return: `"500 Taka: 2 note(s) 100 Taka: 2 note(s) 20 Taka: 1 note(s) 10 Taka: 1 note(s) 2 Taka: 2 note(s)"`

I tried:

```
def splitting_money(amount):
    
    five_hundred = int(amount/500)
    one_hundred = int((amount%500)/100)
    fifty = int(((amount%500)%100)/50)
    twenty = int((((amount%500)%100)%50)/20)
    ten = int(((((amount%500)%100)%50)%20)/10)
    five = int((((((amount%500)%100)%50)%20)%10)/5)
    two = int(((((((amount%500)%100)%50)%20)%10)%5)/2)
    one = int((((((((amount%500)%100)%50)%20)%10)%5)%2)/1)
    
    if amount < 500:
        print ("100 Taka: ",one_hundred,"note(s)","\n", "50 Taka: ",fifty,"note(s)","\n", "20 Taka: ",twenty,"note(s)","\n", "10 Taka: ",ten,"note(s)","\n", "5 Taka: ",five,"note(s)","\n", "2 Taka: ",two,"note(s)","\n", "1 Taka: ",one,"note(s)")
    elif amount >= 500:
        print ("500 Taka: ",five_hundred,"note(s)","\n","100 Taka: ",one_hundred,"note(s)","\n", "50 Taka: ",fifty,"note(s)","\n", "20 Taka: ",twenty,"note(s)","\n", "10 Taka: ",ten,"note(s)","\n", "5 Taka: ",five,"note(s)","\n", "2 Taka: ",two,"note(s)","\n", "1 Taka: ",one,"note(s)")  '\n' splitting_money(1234)
```

Output came:

```
500 Taka:  2 note(s)                                                                                          
100 Taka:  2 note(s)                                                                                               
50 Taka:  0 note(s)                                                                                                  
20 Taka:  1 note(s)                                                                                                   
10 Taka:  1 note(s)                                                                                                  5 Taka:  0 note(s)                                                                                                           
2 Taka:  2 note(s)                                                                                                   
1 Taka:  0 note(s)`
```

This doesn't look neat. What should I do?

Comment: What does "doesn't look neat" actually mean?

Comment: I suggest you use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ if you're looking for a code review.

Comment: Unless you have a specific output in mind, there is no actual question here

Answer (score -1):

Use divmod

```
def to_notes(val,notes):
    remainder = val
    results = {}
    for _n in notes:
        n,remainder = divmod(remainder,_n)
        results[_n]=n
    return results

results = to_notes(1475,[500,100,50,20,10,5,1])
```

To format is trivial

```
' '.join([f'{k} taka {v} note(s)' for k,v in results.items() if v > 0])
```

Comment: This won't always work. For example, if you do `to_notes(110,[50, 20])`, it returns `{50: 2, 20: 0}` (it's missing 10 dollars).